# Merge rows with columns in different format pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I've a dataframe where I have n number of columns of same header eg. Sales, Sales 1, Sales 2 etc.

And the data is rows of multiple records with a column having ID and ID column has duplicate values.

Sales column has a first row stating the month eg Jan, Feb etc for Sales Sales 1 respectively

```
Sales      Sales1     Sales2
Jan 2000  Feb 2000   Month 2000
2000       3000       4000
```

I've filtered the Sales column into a dataframe

```
sales_df= df.filter(regex=('Sales*'))
```

Now I want to merge this with the other records but I want to merge it with columns like SalesMonth SalesValue where I transform the data into Jan 2000 Feb 3000 etc

Output I'm after is

```
X     Y   ID SalesMonth Sales
xxx yyyy 001 Jan 2000   2000
```

EDIT 1: Input file

```
ID    Desc       Sales      Sales1     Sales2
                 Month     Month      Month
                 Jan 2000  Feb 2000   Month 2000
 1    Desc1      10         20         30
 1    Desc1      11         21         31
 2    Desc2      7          Nan         0
 3    Desc3     10         20          10
```

Answer (score 0):

You need create `MultiIndex` in columns first, then reshape by [`unstack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.unstack.html) and last [`reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
print (df)
      Sales    Sales1      Sales2
0  Jan 2000  Feb 2000  Month 2000
1      2000      3000        4000
2      7000      8000        3000

#MultiIndex by first row
df.columns = [df.columns, df.iloc[0]]
#remove first row by indexing - [1:]
df = df.iloc[1:].unstack().reset_index(name='val')
df.columns = ['a','b','c','val']
print (df)
        a           b  c   val
0   Sales    Jan 2000  0  2000
1   Sales    Jan 2000  1  7000
2  Sales1    Feb 2000  0  3000
3  Sales1    Feb 2000  1  8000
4  Sales2  Month 2000  0  4000
5  Sales2  Month 2000  1  3000
```

If input is `file` better is use parameter `header` for `MultiIndex`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Sales;Sales1;Sales2
Jan 2000;Feb 2000;Month 2000
2000;3000;4000
7000;8000;3000"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), sep=';',header=[0,1])
print (df)

     Sales   Sales1     Sales2
  Jan 2000 Feb 2000 Month 2000
0     2000     3000       4000
1     7000     8000       3000

print (df.columns)
MultiIndex(levels=[['Sales', 'Sales1', 'Sales2'], ['Feb 2000', 'Jan 2000', 'Month 2000']],
           labels=[[0, 1, 2], [1, 0, 2]])
```

---

```
df = df.unstack().reset_index(name='val')
df.columns = ['a','b','c','val']
print (df)
        a           b  c   val
0   Sales    Jan 2000  0  2000
1   Sales    Jan 2000  1  7000
2  Sales1    Feb 2000  0  3000
3  Sales1    Feb 2000  1  8000
4  Sales2  Month 2000  0  4000
5  Sales2  Month 2000  1  3000
```

Comment: I tried loading with header but the first column is getting indexed which I dont & my file has other columns as well, what I saw the header become like 'unnamed.', 'unnamed', 'total' etc - any clue what I'm  not doing right?

Comment: @user6083088 - It is really data dependent problem, is possible share some file with 3 rows, mainly with 2 headers rows?

Comment: Updated the post with new sample data

Comment: Thank you. I think need `pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=[0,1], header=[0,1,2])` but without file not easy test.

Comment: Nope it isn't working but the sample data I gave is exactly the way the data exists but with more columns not just 5 columns. The first row is column header, second row is empty for most columns besides the one which has multiple values like Sales etc

Comment: @user6083088 - I ask for file, because sometimes it working, sometimes not :( Obviously thit is really dependent of dta...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171601/discussion-between-user6083088-and-jezrael).